Error HTTP 500.19 internal server 0x8007000d
estuve intentando realizar deploy de mi asp.net web core api de forma local siguiendo los pasos tal cual pero me encuentro con la siguiente imagen 
mi archivo web.config contiene lo siguiente:


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\API Camiones.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
      <customErrors mode="On" />
    </system.webServer>
    <system.web>
      <customErrors mode="On" />
    </system.web>
  </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: 38d869a0-78b2-41cf-87a0-b10a0c759fae-->



ya instale el modulo aspnetcoremodulev2 y reinicie pero nada continua el error

Este problema suele generarse debido a que no tienes todos los paquetes necesarios en tu servidor para poder ejecutar la aplicación de .NET.
Te recomiendo visitar la siguiente página y revisar que el servidor donde estás alojando la aplicación contenga los paquetes requeridos.
Link de paquetes .NET
Porfa, no olvides instalar el hosting bundle dentro del servidor, sin este nunca va a levantar tu aplicación, adicionalmente, asegurate de que el paquete que instales concuerde con la versión de .NET que estás utilizando.

Espero te sea de ayuda.
Saludos.
